# Update table1 from table2 with top1 row

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to update table1 from table2 with  the top 1 row with the following SQL statement but no rows get updated even if matches are there.

**Table1**:

```
partno avprice
--------------
P001    0
P002    0
P003    0
P004    0
P005    0
```

**Table2**:

```
id(PK)  partno  unitprice
-------------------------
1       P001       0.65
2       P001       0.90
3       P003       1.20
4       P005       0.25
5       P005       1.35
```

SQL

```
update table1 
set avgprice = (select top 1 unitprice 
                from table2 
                left join table1 on table2.partno = table1.partno 
                order by tabl2.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an update join here, but in this case we can join to a subquery which finds the first unit price for each part, first being as ordered by the `id` column in `table2`.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.avgprice = t2.unitprice
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT partno, unitprice,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY partno ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM table2
) t2
    ON t1.partno = t2.partno
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with my syntax.  See if you can make my query work.

Comment: I just copied the sql to the query window in sql server 2008 r2. table1 and table2 already exists in the db. I still get the above mentioned error.

Comment: I updated my answer for SQL Server.  For future reference, only tag with the database you are actually using.